# Azure scaling on memory metric

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service

We have got a memory intensive application. We would like to scale up if the memory consumption is too high on our servers.How can we achieve this using Azure websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **preview portal** (https://portal.azure.com) you can add a **memory percentage** metric in the website settings and scale using that metric.  When you get to the **scale** blade, click on the **add metric** button at the top. Then select the **memory percentage** metric, define your thresholds for scaling up and down, and then save the metric.  Then, back in the **scale** blade set your Autoscale mode to **performance** and choose the memory percentage metric you just added.

Here is a screenshot showing what this looks like for a sample website I have.

[image]